# Azure VM shutdown using variables in Terraform

Tags: azure, variables, terraform, string-concatenation, terraform-provider-azure

I have a requirement to use variables to set notification emails to a list of people in Terraform to shut down a resource. However, the emails to be sent are required to combine three declared variables, so the module will look something like the below:

```
  notification_settings {
    enabled         = true
    time_in_minutes = "180"
    email           = format("%s", "${var.config.person1};${var.config.person2};${var.config.person3}")
  }
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be changed from:

```
email = format("%s", "${var.config.person1};${var.config.person2};${var.config.person3}")
```

to:

```
email = format("%s;%s;%s", var.config.person1, var.config.person2, var.config.person3)
```

More information on `format` function can be found in [1].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar but it looks like this:

```
  notification_settings {
    enabled         = true
    time_in_minutes = "120"
    email           = "${var.person1};${var.person2};${var.person3}"
  }
```

Also, check your time in minutes setting if your using the azurerm_dev_test_global_vm_shutdown_schedule resource you can't extend the shutdown event beyond 120 minutes.